# PHP SQL-Cache with serialize, optimization?

Tags: php, caching, optimization

I have a Database and a table with about 200 mb data. (Product descriptions, and a lot of values)
I need this values to display some Detail-Pages. So I plan to use a little cache-system to speed things up. I think serialize is the better way to go with php.

Now I wonder how to save my data best, to get the best speed.
Every product as one file, one file with all products or chunks (lets say 100 products per file)?

I want to store the informations in an object like this, serialize it and save it:

```
class saveObj
{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 0,100"
$time;
$data;    
};
```

filename: sql_products_0_100.data

Will my plan be efficient or does anyone know a way to optimize?

(I would create all data files once per day)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hard to say without writing some test code and doing some profiling.

If you go down the 100 products per file route, are all the 100 products going be used to generate the page?

Having 1 file per product means that the disk will need to seek alot if you need data about 100 files per page.

Having 100 products per file means that if your page only requires 1 product, then it needs to read all the data in and then search for the appropriate product to extract.

My suggestion would be to investigate APC. The cache is stored in memory, so access is extremely fast and you can store 1 product per key, which should simplify retrival and storage.

If load increases and you are load balancing across multiple servers, then you can look at memcached, which is a distributed memory caching system.

Comment: I thought about Memcached, but memcached seems to have a problem with the shopping-software (prestashop) Using files I would also have the ability to change data with some python-scripts. Product-data must be "updated" once per day and so must  be all product-pages for crawling (google merchants, other searching sites).

Comment: For memcached, if the values are stored in memory, couldn't this cause some problems if there are too many values stored?

Comment: No, memcached is fine with that. For example, if you might have a server with 8Gb of ram. You can then allocate 7Gb to memcache for storing objects. This should be plently for your purposes. If that is not enough, you can add more machines to the pool. However, if you are just running 1 server, then look at APC as it is perfect for single server caching.

Comment: allright, i will try all 3 methods, file-cache, memcached and apc. I will look which is the fastest method for my purpose and then ill decide. I have only 4 gb real memory on my server now, but I can upgrade if necessary.

Comment: That's great :) Profiling should be able to tell you what's best for your purposes. Although, you will probably find that caching to memory is probably the fastest in terms of read and write.